# Email Forwarding Service to use with my domain?

Tags: email

I just registered my domain with namecheap. One of the main purposes of me registering my domain was to use the email forwarding service. Well unfortunately i found out after i registered my domain that Namecheap only has 7 unique forwarding possibilities. That's not nearly enough. Does anyone know of a relatively cheap and reliable email forwarding service i could use with my domain?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Gmail for your domain (Google Apps for Business or the regular version). It's fairly simple to set up email forwarding, or domain aliasing if you want.

Alternatively, you could just get a decent web host for less than $10/month (e.g. DreamHost) that doesn't put limits on things like the number of email forwards you're allowed to have.

Personally, I'd just switch to a better web host. Since most web hosts that limit things like email accounts or subdomains generally aren't very good anyways and will end up costing you more in time/work/money in the long run.